# Apache redirect 301 based on domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've changed links on website a little bit so it's more SEO friendly for our international sites, so I simply translated word "game" and links are now like:

```
domain.com/games/id-123
domain.pl/gry/id-123
domain.de/spiele/id-123
```

Previously website links were like:

```
domain.com/games/id-123
domain.pl/games/id-123
domain.de/games/id-123
```

Now I want to make apache 301 redirect so links from other websites, google, etc will be redirect to new addressses:

```
domain.pl/games/id-123 -> domain.pl/gry/id-123
domain.de/games/id-123 -> domain.de/spiele/id-123
```

I need to add that of course "**id-123**" is and id of a game, so its "dynamic" and I can't make simple redirect like "Redirect 301 /gry/ domain.com/spiele/".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use mod_rewrite and `%{HTTP_HOST}` to match the appropriate domain in a `RewriteCond`, and route accordingly:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Domain ends with .pl
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.pl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^games/(.*)$ gry/$1 [L,R=301]

# Domain ends with .de
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^games/(.*)$ spiele/$1 [L,R=301]
```